# VBscript - How do I change anonymous authentication settings for a specific site?

Tags: authentication, iis-7, vbscript

I'm writing a VBscript that I would like to alter the anyonymous authentication configuration for a specific site on my web server. However, I'm unsure of how this is done in the commit path. Currently, I am able to change the setting on a global scale, but I only want to target one particular site folder. My best guess was to simply include the site path at the end of MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST.

```
'CHANGE ANONYMOUS AUTHENTICATION GLOBALLY (working code):

Set adminManager = CreateObject("Microsoft.ApplicationHost.WritableAdminManager")

Set anonymousAuthenticationSection = adminManager.GetAdminSection("system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication", "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST")

anonymousAuthenticationSection.Properties.Item("enabled").Value = True
anonymousAuthenticationSection.Properties.Item("userName").Value = "myUser"
anonymousAuthenticationSection.Properties.Item("password").Value = "myPass"

adminManager.CommitChanges()



'MY BEST GUESS AT TARGETING A SPECIFIC SITE (returns error 80070005):

Set anonymousAuthenticationSection = adminManager.GetAdminSection("system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication", "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Sites/InsideFTL/Corp/redirects/netXposure")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that you have above should work, are you running it from an elevated command prompt?
You could also try to make sure that it is committing to ApplicationHost.config to make sure it is not a locking issue by setting CommitPath, and make sure that the identity under you are running the script has write access to it.

```
'CHANGE ANONYMOUS AUTHENTICATION For Default Web Site:
Set adminManager = CreateObject("Microsoft.ApplicationHost.WritableAdminManager")
adminManager.CommitPath = "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST"
Set anonymousAuthenticationSection = adminManager.GetAdminSection("system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication", "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site")
anonymousAuthenticationSection.Properties.Item("enabled").Value = True
anonymousAuthenticationSection.Properties.Item("userName").Value = "myUser"
anonymousAuthenticationSection.Properties.Item("password").Value = "myPass"
adminManager.CommitChanges()
```

Comment: How could you make it use the application pool identity instead of a specific user?